# Caching images on pages with PHP

Tags: php, caching, curl, php-5.6

How can I (if possible) cache all images that are on the page so that I have easy access to them whenever I use cURL on a page using PHP?

Comment: Are you trying to scrape a page using php?

Comment: too broad question, caching/balancing is a big topic